# Проблема с типами при использовании интерфейса в TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

**Использую интерфейс:**

```
interface IComponents {
  minValue: HTMLInputElement;
  isVertical: HTMLInputElement;
  maxValue: HTMLInputElement;
  step: HTMLInputElement;
  thumbLeft: HTMLInputElement;
  thumbRight: HTMLInputElement;
  horizontal: HTMLInputElement;
  isRange: HTMLInputElement;
  isTip: HTMLInputElement;
  isBar: HTMLInputElement;
  isStep: HTMLInputElement;
}
export default IComponents;
```

При реализации свойств интерфейса, TS выдает ошибку:

**Тип "HTMLInputElement | null" не может быть назначен для типа "HTMLInputElement".**

*Читал, что в таких случаях необходима доп. проверка, либо использование as. Пробовал as, но мест с такой ошибкой много, выглядит слишком громоздко. Также отключал strict mode, и конечно все работало, но без него никуда.*

```
private render (): void {
    const panel = document.createElement('div');
    panel.classList.add('panel');
    panel.innerHTML = tplPanel;

    this.components = {
      minValue: panel.querySelector('.js-panel__min-input'),
      maxValue: panel.querySelector('.js-panel__max-input'),
      thumbLeft: panel.querySelector('.js-panel__from-input'),
      thumbRight: panel.querySelector('.js-panel__to-input'),
      step: panel.querySelector('.js-panel__step-input'),
      horizontal: panel.querySelector('.js-panel__horizontal-input'),
      isVertical: panel.querySelector('.js-panel__vertical-input'),
      isRange: panel.querySelector('.js-panel__withRange-input'),
      isTip: panel.querySelector('.js-panel__withTip-input'),
      isStep: panel.querySelector('.js-panel__withStep-input'),
      isBar: panel.querySelector('.js-panel__withBar-input')
    };

    this.components.thumbRight.disabled = true;
    this.domParent.appendChild(panel);
    this.changeSettings(this.modelSettings);
  }
  
export default IComponents;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) может не найти элемент и вернет в этом случае `null`.

В интерфейсе наличие элементов **обязательно**.

Если свойства могут быть `null` можно поменять им тип, например

```
minValue: HTMLInputElement | null;
```

Если свойства не могут быть `null`, тогда нужно определиться, что делать в случае, если элемент не будет найден.

Также, можно указать компилятору, что ты уверен, что значение `null` не будет возвращено. Для этого можно использовать [Non-null Assertion Operator (Postfix
!)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-)

```
minValue: panel.querySelector('.js-panel__min-input')!,
```